# Android MediaCodec API not working in Child Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-5.0-lollipop, android-mediacodec

In Android, I tried using **MediaCodec** api `(MediaCodecList.getCodecCount())` in **Main Thread** seems working fine with no issues. But the same api when i used inside its **child thread**, ends up with application crash.

The crash log was stated below:

> *A/libc(18571): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xe0 in tid 18600*

The above scenario was tested with **Andriod 5.0.2** mobile device.

Why such behaviour and any idea to resolve this ?

Comment: Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) does lots of MediaCodec work in different threads without crashing. You'll need to be more specific about what you're doing. FWIW, your problem sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772854/

Comment: Please find my code snippet on the following link http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/mediacodec-api-crashes-on-samsung-s5-lollipop-502/201/285497?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~

Comment: @vgokul129, did you find  solution for this issue?. i too face similar issue. My application runs service in a different process, and main app communicate with this with the help of AIDL interface. Interestingly, if i run getCodecCount() on the main thread context it works, but, if i run the same API  into different thread with help of handler, i see the same crash. Please let me know if you find the solution?

Comment: @fadden,  Does MediaCodec relies on UI Thread Context?. Kindly let know if i overlook something?.